# ADAL.js to get Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.Models.EmbedToken

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I am developing a javascript client based application which will embed the powerbi dashboards. I need help in following.

1. How do I create Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext object or its equivalent at client side using using ADAL.js?
2. How do I create Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential object or its equivalent at client side using using ADAL.js?

I need this to be implemented so I can use power js libraries to embed the dasboards/reports.

Regards,

Yasotha

Comment: what have you tried so far? please add some code

Comment: I achieved the overall goal on a Azure web App following this model. https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/App%20Owns%20Data/PowerBIEmbedded_AppOwnsData

Comment: But I haven't got any solid solution using JS yet

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate an authentication context in adal.js as follows:

`var config = {
        instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
        tenant: '[Enter your tenant here, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]',
        clientId: '[Enter your client_id here, e.g. g075edef-0efa-453b-997b-de1337c29185]',
    };
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);`

Please refer to this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi) for an idea of how to get tokens and use them to call an API. In this sample, the JS client calls its own backend api, but once you acquire a token for the powerbi API, you will need to set it as a bearer token in the call to the powerbi API.

Adal.js uses the Oauth [implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-dev-understanding-oauth2-implicit-grant) for authentication and does not support flows that use UserCredential.